# How to skip intro on Counter Strike Condition Zero?

Tags: counter-strike

How can I skip the intro on Condition Zero? It is annoying; and keeps me from getting into the play quickly.

The intro contains three clips: The Ritual, Turtle Rock Studio, and Steam at the opening.

Answer (score 1):

I have no Condition Zero but for all other Valve games I have using `-novid` in launch parameters works, so you can give a try.